# Google Sheets Script Editor View Only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If you have the link to the Google Sheet Script Editor you can view it in read only mode if you have the link to get there but it seems you can't have access to that link unless you have edit permission... is there anyway to get to the view only Script Editor without having the link or copying the entire project?

Comment: Have we established that a bound script can be shared without also sharing the container? There "is" a `Share`option (File>Share) in the Script Editor, but I couldn't get it to complete a share where the  the script was "view" only.

Comment: @Tedinoz let's test it, share with me a script, and then I will bring it up and then revoke my access and we can see if it let's me stay in read only mode, do you have Skype?

Comment: Although I don't know whether this is possible(It wasn't possible during brief testing), It's  safe to assume, read access to the spreadsheet includes read access to the bound script project.  Why do you want to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that.

As explained [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts), if you only have view access to the parent file, the only way to access the script is by making a copy of the parent file.

And a bound script cannot be shared without sharing the container file (they cannot be detached from the file they are bound to, as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)).

Comment: If you have a copy of the script link you can view it in read only mode which is nice than having to make an entire copy of the sheet just to see it yourself.

Comment: Of course, but as you said before, `you can't have access to that link unless you have edit permission`!

Comment: so basically unless the owner gave you the link.